# Можно ли с сайта открыть отзыв на Ютубе сразу с субтитрами и нужным языком?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, youtube, youtube-api

Мне нужно, чтобы на моем сайте при клике по видеоотзыву открывался айфрейм с видео, которое лежит на Ютубе (это уже реализовано). Причем, в зависимости от текущего языка видео должно открываться с субтитрами и соответствующим языком. Реально ли это сделать? Если бы можно было при открытии видео передать параметром язык и обязательность субтитров, то было бы отлично. 
Вопрос - это вообще реально? И если нет, то как можно выйти из положения?

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters), язык интерфейса можно задать при помощи параметра `hl`, а для включения субтитров используется параметр `cc_load_policy` со значением `1`. При необходимости можно использовать параметр `cc_lang_pref`, чтобы задать язык субтитров. Этот параметр работает аналогично параметру `hl`.

Стоит иметь в виду, что `cc_load_policy=1` не работает с автогенерированными субтитрами, их нужно включать вручную.

Пример использования:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/QRS8MkLhQmM?hl=en&cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=ru&autoplay=1
```